# when to use a Meteor Method vs normal function?

Tags: meteor

I've got, I think, a relatively simple question. I'm wondering in Meteor, especially when I'm defining server-side functions that I want the client to be able to call, when do I use a method vs a normal function? Why can't I just use a global function in my Meteor server code instead of defining a Meteor Method?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions defined only the server are only accessible to server code (even if defined globally). So for example, if you had a function defined in `server/util.js` it would **not** be available to the client.

You could, however, define a function that was global to both the server and the client by placing it outside of the `server` and `client` directories, e.g. in `lib`.

Generally, you would choose to create a method over a function when you want a side effect which should only be produced on the server. Examples:

- you need to sign a URL and keep the key only on the server
- you need to perform a database operation that can only be done on the server (due to limitations of minimongo)

Important note - method calls from the client are asynchronous (you need to provide a callback function to know the result of the method), so that may also factor into your decision.

Comment: thanks, let me ask you this then, what's the point of a client-side Meteor method? I've seen those too

and yup, thanks for the callback function tip for client Meteor method calls, took me awhile to figure that out at first

Comment: When you define a method on the client it's called a stub - this is done for latency compensation. You can find more information on stubs in the [methods section](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) of the docs and in [this video](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-methods).